# Excel for MAC - ExportAsFixedFormat ignores the print area and generate too many pages instead of one

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pdf-generation

I have a vba excel application that populates some information into a sheet and then exports that sheet to PDF. The sheet is a template of mine, and its print area is fixed by default in order to generate a one-page PDF for each export.

It works perfectly for Windows, generating one-page PDFs for each export. However, when using the same code in a Macbook (OS X El Capitan) with a 15.38 Excel version, the generated PDF contains lots of pages because the default print area is ignored. If I debug and stop the execution just before ExportAsFixedFormat statement the print area of the sheet is OK (the default one) and I can manually save it as one-page PDF, so I don't know where is the issue... I hope someone can help me here! This is the code I use for the PDF generation:

```
Sheets("mySheet").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myPath & "\" & myName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: I'm not really into vba for mac, but can you set the printarea of the sheet via VBA, by using Sheets("mySheet").PageSetup.PrintArea?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. I tried to set the print area as suggested but the problem persists. Not matter which is the printed area, ExportAsFixedFormat command generates 8 pages instead of one. It seems that somehow the print area is divided in pieces... Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Normally in Windows, ExportAsFixedFormat creates the same as when you look at the print preview. If you look at the print preview, do you see differences there as well?

Comment: If I run the code and stop it just before ExportAsFixedFormat statement the print area is as expected and, if I manually export to PDF, I get the expected one page document.